# Get data from a template back into the component

Tags: angular

I'm a angular2 newbie and I have a question about getting data back from a template. I have the following template:

```
<h2>Set parameters</h2>
<button (click)="onClick()">Calculate</button>
<h3>Sailing profiles</h3>
<label *ngFor="let sailingProfile of sailingProfiles">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{sailingProfile.title}}" value="{{sailingProfile.title}}">
    {{sailingProfile.title}}<br>
</label>
<h3>Counters</h3>
<label *ngFor="let counter of counters">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{counter.type}}" value="{{counter.type}}">
    <input type="text"> {{counter.type}}<br>
</label>
```

The purpose is to select one ore more sailing profiles and select one ore more counters and add a value for each selected counter. The component which uses this template is:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from "@angular/core";
import {CounterService} from "../service/counter.service";
import {SailingProfileService} from "../service/sailing-profile.service";
import {CounterModel} from "../model/counter";
import {SailingProfileModel} from "../model/sailing-profile";

@Component({
    selector: 'params',
    templateUrl: '../../template/params.html',
    providers: [CounterService, SailingProfileService],
})
export class ParamsComponent {
    @Output() paramsUpdated: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    counters: CounterModel[] = [];
    sailingProfiles: SailingProfileModel[] = [];

    constructor(private counterService: CounterService, private sailingProfileService: SailingProfileService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.counterService.getCounters().subscribe(c => this.counters = c);
        this.sailingProfileService.getSailingProfiles().subscribe(s => this.sailingProfiles = s);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.paramsUpdated.emit('test');
    }
}
```

How do I get the selected sailing profiles and counters with their values back in the onClick() method? The desired result is a string which looks like this:

```
{"counters":[{"type":"Running hours","value":6000},{"type":"Seconds","value":31536000}],"sailing_profiles":[{"title": "Continuous sailing"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `value`

It will look something like this

```xml
<label *ngFor="let sailingProfile of sailingProfiles">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{sailingProfile.title}}" [(ngModel)]='sailingProfile.checkBoxState'>
    {{sailingProfile.title}}<br>
</label>
<h3>Counters</h3>
<label *ngFor="let counter of counters">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{counter.type}}" [(ngModel)]='counter.checkBoxState'>
    <input type="text"> {{counter.type}}<br>
</label>
```

Now when you access `this.counter` or `this.sailingProfiles` inside `onClick`, you will see that `checkBoxState : true` is present for every selected checkbox. It should look like

```
this.counters = [
  {"type":"Running hours","value":6000},
  {"type":"Seconds","value":31536000, checkBoxState: true}
];

this.sailingProfiles = [
  {"title": "Continuous sailing", checkBoxState: true}
]
```

Now you can get the values of the selected objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a form, then you can get your data as `form.value`. Best use the `@angular/forms` bundle and in your bootstrap do:

```
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms(),
```

to get the current forms API. This is a good up to date tutorial on Angular 2 forms: http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/